# Cannot get desired result from complex R named column manipulation

Tags: r

I need to convert some data from two named columns on a single multidimensional list into a single list with two columns, and the data in each row in the result needs to be from the matching row in the source list. See the following pseudocode:

```r
object <- data.frame()
object$Property1 <- c('a', 'b', 'c')
object$Property2 <- c(1, 2, 3)
object$Property3 <- c('X', 'Y', 'Z')
object$Property4 <- c('other', 'data', 'here')

result = matrix(NA, nrow=length(object), ncol=2)

# This is what I need help with
result$Property1 <- object$Property1
result$Property2 <- object$Property2
```

After the above code runs, the `result` variable should have this value:

| row | result$Property1 | result$Property2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **1** | `'a'` | `1` |
| **2** | `'b'` | `2` |
| **3** | `'c'` | `3` |

`result` should have no other columns.

---

I have tried the exact syntax shown above, `result <- list(object$Property1, object$Property2)`, and `result <- c(object$Property1, object$Property2)`, but I keep getting a one-dimensional list with the values `['a', 'b', 'c', 1, 2, 3]`. I am using R 3.3.2 on Windows 10 version 20H2. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to construct data.frame would be to creates the vectors (if needed) and then pass them in `data.frame`.  In the OP's code, the `data.frame` was created as a 0 row, 0 column and it fails when we add columns with `$`.

```
Property1 <- c('a', 'b', 'c')
Property2 <- c(1, 2, 3)
Property3 <- c('X', 'Y', 'Z')
Property4 <- c('other', 'data', 'here')

object <- data.frame(Property1, Property2, Property3, Property4)
```

-ouptut

```
> object
  Property1 Property2 Property3 Property4
1         a         1         X     other
2         b         2         Y      data
3         c         3         Z      here
```

Answer (score 1):

With akrun's data: we could also use `tibble`: See here:

```
Property1 <- c('a', 'b', 'c')
Property2 <- c(1, 2, 3)
Property3 <- c('X', 'Y', 'Z')
Property4 <- c('other', 'data', 'here')

library(tibble)
object <- tibble(Property1, Property2, Property3, Property4)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 4
  Property1 Property2 Property3 Property4
  <chr>         <dbl> <chr>     <chr>    
1 a                 1 X         other    
2 b                 2 Y         data     
3 c                 3 Z         here
```